# My web app latest code Apps Script runtime powered by Chrome V8 ERROR "You do not have permission to access the requested document"

Tags: google-apps-script

Web app run latest code.

Execute the app as owner

Who has access to the app: in company

I'm a editor and in google script I don't have have read access any document. But I can test code by run web app latest code.

When enabled new Apps Script runtime powered by Chrome V8 (alpha) for this project, I received the notice "Exception: Document ****** is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or you don't have read access?)".

After, I disabled new Apps Script runtime powered by Chrome V8 => I received the notice "You do not have permission to access the requested document."

I couldn't run web app latest code as before. How to fix it? Thanks :(

Comment: If you create a new Apps Script project with the same content and make a new deployment - does it fix the problem?

Comment: V8 was just released (Feb 5 2020) so there are bound to be a few glitches here and there. You may want to send in a bug report via Google's Issue tracker.

Comment: @ziganotschka If I create a new Apps Script project with the same content and make a new deployment - problem fixed :). And if I enabled, after disabled V8, problem come back :)

Comment: As Dimu Designs says, V8 is still very new and still has some issues. So maybe after reporting the problem to Google you need to wait some time until the problem is fixed and keep using V7 in the meantime.